# connecting to aws and executing a query using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, steampipe

Hi I am trying to use the code for connecting aws through steampipe and executing the query cd steampipe-mod-aws-compliance && steampipe check aws_compliance.benchmark.cis_v200 as I see the code is not working is there something which I am missing thank you.

```
def run_shell(cmd: str) -> str:
    try:
        result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
        output, error = result.communicate()
        if error:
            print("Error occurred:", error)
        return output.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception occurred:", e)
        return ""



def aws_login(access_key: str, secret_key: str) -> None:
    try:
        # Use the provided access_key and secret_key directly to create the S3 client
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

        # Use the tenant_id in AWS API calls, if needed
        # For example, you can list S3 buckets to verify credentials
        response = s3_client.list_buckets()

        # If the API call succeeds, then the credentials are valid
        print("AWS login successful.")
        print("S3 Buckets:")
        for bucket in response['Buckets']:
            print(bucket['Name'])

    except Exception as e:
        print("AWS login failed. Please check your credentials.")
        print("Error occurred:", e)


aws_login(access_key, secret_key)

import os

def create_steam_config() -> None:
    cfg_content = ""

    content_header = """connection "aws_all" {
    type        = "aggregator"
    plugin      = "aws"
    connections = ["aws_*"]
}

"""

    cfg_content += content_header

    content_connection = """connection "aws_sub_1" {
    plugin      = "aws"
    region      = "us-east-1"
    }

"""

    cfg_content += content_connection

    # Expand the ~ symbol to the user's home directory
    config_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.steampipe/config/aws.spc")
    
    with open(config_path, "w") as cfg_f:
        cfg_f.write(cfg_content)

# Call the function to create the Steam config file
create_steam_config()

command = "cd steampipe-mod-aws-compliance && steampipe check aws_compliance.benchmark.cis_v200 --export=cis_v200.json"

try:
    # Execute the command in the shell
    result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    if result.returncode == 0:
        print("Command executed successfully.")
        print("Output:")
        print(result.stdout)
    else:
        print("Command execution failed.")
        print("Error:")
        print(result.stderr)
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```